# How can I parse JSON in android using SOAP?

Tags: android, json, web-services, soap

I am trying to parse JSON data from web service using SOAP in android. My data is showing in debugger but not in the application. I am using SOAP because in my WebService JSON data is in XML tags. When I call JSONOBJECT in my MainActivity it throws an exception & do not enter in the for loop. It usually give me error that the string can not be converted into JSONOBJECT or integer can not be converted into JSONOBJECT. I want to show ll the data inside a list for which I am using another class **TableAdapter** and I am also using a Model named **Table** in which getter & setter functions are called.Tell me what to do.

### Here is my MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyInterface
{

ListView List;
TableAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Table> tableArrayList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    tableArrayList = new ArrayList<Table>();

    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/xxxx";
    String OPERATION_NAME = "xxxx";

    WebServiceHandler webServiceHandler = new WebServiceHandler(MainActivity.this);
    webServiceHandler.setValues(SOAP_ACTION, OPERATION_NAME);
    try
    {
        webServiceHandler.executeProcedure();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "cant connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
@Override
public void StartedRequest()
{

}



   @Override
    public void CodeFinished(String methodName, Object Data) {
//        String str = Data.toString();
//        if (str != null)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(data));
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Table");
                for( int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++ )
                {
                    Table table = new Table();
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    table.setRequestID(jsonObject1.getInt("Request_ID"));
                    table.setOwnerID(jsonObject1.getInt("Owner_ID"));
                    table.setCustomerID(jsonObject1.getInt("Customer_ID"));
                    table.setAssetName(jsonObject1.getString("AssetName"));
                    table.setAddress(jsonObject1.getString("Address"));
                    table.setDateTime(jsonObject1.getString("DateTime"));
                    table.setOwnerName(jsonObject1.getString("OwnerName"));
                    table.setCustomerName(jsonObject1.getString("CustomerName"));

                    tableArrayList.add(table);
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            TableAdapter adapter = new TableAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, tableArrayList);
            List.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }


@Override
    public void CodeFinishedWithException(Exception ex, String exp)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void CodeEndedRequest()
    {

    }
}
```

### This is the code

in which I am facing problem. Debugger do not enter in this for loop.

```
 @Override
    public void CodeFinished(String methodName, Object Data) {
//        String str = Data.toString();
//        if (str != null)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(data));
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Table");
                for( int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++ )
                {
                    Table table = new Table();
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    table.setRequestID(jsonObject1.getInt("Request_ID"));
                    table.setOwnerID(jsonObject1.getInt("Owner_ID"));
                    table.setCustomerID(jsonObject1.getInt("Customer_ID"));
                    table.setAssetName(jsonObject1.getString("AssetName"));
                    table.setAddress(jsonObject1.getString("Address"));
                    table.setDateTime(jsonObject1.getString("DateTime"));
                    table.setOwnerName(jsonObject1.getString("OwnerName"));
                    table.setCustomerName(jsonObject1.getString("CustomerName"));

                    tableArrayList.add(table);
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            TableAdapter adapter = new TableAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, tableArrayList);
            List.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

### Here is my WebService

```
   <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
{ "Table": [ { "Request_ID": 2112, "Owner_ID": 1668, "Customer_ID": 1476, "AssetName": "Two Bed Room House", "Address": "xyz", "DateTime": "12/24/2016 1:18:44 PM", "OwnerName": "IAmAOwner", "OwnerNumber": "+923363636013", "CustomerName": "arham" }, { "Request_ID": 2113, "Owner_ID": 1668, "Customer_ID": 1476, "AssetName": "Two Bed Room House", "Address": "xyz", "DateTime": "12/24/2016 1:45:00 PM", "OwnerName": "IAmAOwner", "OwnerNumber": "+923363636013", "CustomerName": "arham" }, { "Request_ID": 2121, "Owner_ID": 1668, "Customer_ID": 1476, "AssetName": "Two Bed Room House", "Address": "xyz", "DateTime": "12/26/2016 3:57:45 PM", "OwnerName": "IAmAOwner", "OwnerNumber": "+923363636013", "CustomerName": "arham" }, { "Request_ID": 2124, "Owner_ID": 1668, "Customer_ID": 1476, "AssetName": "Two Bed Room House", "Address": "xyz", "DateTime": "12/26/2016 4:43:19 PM", "OwnerName": "IAmAOwner", "OwnerNumber": "+923363636013", "CustomerName": "arham" }, { "Request_ID": 2125, "Owner_ID": 1668, "Customer_ID": 1476, "AssetName": "Two Bed Room House", "Address": "xyz", "DateTime": "12/26/2016 4:50:39 PM", "OwnerName": "IAmAOwner", "OwnerNumber": "+923363636013", "CustomerName": "arham" }, { "Request_ID": 2126, "Owner_ID": 1668, "Customer_ID": 1476, "AssetName": "Two Bed Room House", "Address": "xyz", "DateTime": "12/27/2016 1:19:32 PM", "OwnerName": "IAmAOwner", "OwnerNumber": "+923363636013", "CustomerName": "arham" }, { "Request_ID": 2127, "Owner_ID": 1668, "Customer_ID": 1476, "AssetName": "Two Bed Room House", "Address": "xyz", "DateTime": "12/27/2016 1:27:36 PM", "OwnerName": "IAmAOwner", "OwnerNumber": "+923363636013", "CustomerName": "arham" }, { "Request_ID": 2128, "Owner_ID": 1668, "Customer_ID": 1476, "AssetName": "Two Bed Room House", "Address": "xyz", "DateTime": "12/27/2016 1:35:38 PM", "OwnerName": "IAmAOwner", "OwnerNumber": "+923363636013", "CustomerName": "arham" }, { "Request_ID": 2129, "Owner_ID": 1668, "Customer_ID": 1476, "AssetName": "Two Bed Room House", "Address": "xyz", "DateTime": "12/27/2016 1:38:08 PM", "OwnerName": "IAmAOwner", "OwnerNumber": "+923363636013", "CustomerName": "arham" } ] }
</string>
```

Comment: Post the code where you get an exception and also the error logs.

Comment: @MonishKamble I`ve updted my question and I am not having any errors or anything else in my error logs.

Comment: What is `data` here?

Comment: its Data not data I must have put that by mistake !

Comment: It is in the method Codefinished & using as an object

Comment: What value is passed into `Data`? Add log to print value of `Data` and post it here.

Comment: @MirzaHamza can you explain better what you're looking for?

Comment: I want to show all the data in my webservice inside a list view in android. The problem is when I rum my application it doest not show anything and when I debug the Json string is showing but data is not parsing the way it should be

Answer (score 0):

```
public void CodeFinished(String methodName, Object Data)
```

Here Data is not a string object. this may be causing issue.
This can be a plain java object {may be pojo} class you can not convert it to string.

Comment: What should I do ? Can you please tell ??

Comment: Please debug and check what kind of response it is

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SoapPrimitive resultSoapPrimitive;
resultSoapPrimitive = (SoapPrimitive) Data.getResponse();
if (resultSoapPrimitive != null) {
    result = resultSoapPrimitive.toString();
}
```